# Programa que muestre el numero mayor de un conjunto de números de un fichero

Tags: java, eclipse

Estoy utilizando eclipse y necesito un programa el cual de un documento de texto lleno de números me muestre por pantalla el número mayor. Por ejemplo en el txt (ya que es en ficheros) están los números 21, 45 y 67, pues necesito que por la consola de eclipse se muestre el número mayor que en este caso es el 67. En mi fichero están los números 1,5,7,2,9 y soy capaz de mostrarlos todos pero no soy capaz de mostrar el mayor.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Ejercicio1 {
   public static void muestraContenido(String archivo) throws 
FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        String cadena;

        FileReader f = new FileReader(archivo);
        BufferedReader b = new BufferedReader(f);
        while ((cadena = b.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(cadena);
        }
        b.close();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        muestraContenido("numeros/numeros.txt");
    }
}
```

Comment: Es muy sencillo, a medida que vas mostrando los números almacenas el mayor. ¿Cómo? Pues al iniciar el bucle, el primer número será el mayor, por lo tanto lo almacenas en la variable `mayor`. En la siguiente iteración, comparas el número que estás mostrando con el que tienes almacenado, si es mayor, actualizas la variable `mayor`. Al finalizar todo, el número mayor estará almacenado en la variable `mayor`. Saludos

Comment: Mauricio Contreras Muchas gracias, lo haré

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una forma seria usando [split()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) ya que los numeros estan separados por una "," haciendo ello obtendria un array con todos los numeros y mediante un ciclo for obtienes el mayor de todos

Ejemplo

```
 import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
    import java.io.FileReader;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.Arrays;
    import java.util.stream.Stream;
    
    
    
    public class Ejercicio1 {
       public static void muestraContenido(String archivo) throws 
            FileNotFoundException, IOException {
            String cadena;
    
            FileReader f = new FileReader(archivo);
            BufferedReader b = new BufferedReader(f);
            int mayor=0;
            while ((cadena = b.readLine()) != null) {
//split te regresa un array de tipo String ,hacemos un cast para convertirlo en int
                int[] parts = Stream.of(cadena.split(",")).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray();
                for (int i=0;i<parts.length;i++ ) {
//iteramos y comparamos para obtener el mayor
                   if(mayor<parts[i]){
                      mayor=parts[i];
                   }               
              }         
            }
              
             System.out.println("El mayor es "+mayor);
            b.close();
    
        }
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Dramaturgo 

Comment: Si te sirvió la respuesta,marcala como aceptada ✓.saludos